# How do I install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Asus 1225C netbook?

Tags: installation, usb, ubuntu-netbook, asus

I had to wait a month to receive my Asus 1225C netbook from Adorama Camera and was disappointed to find that it comes without Ubuntu installed. I have Eeebuntu 12.04 on a flash drive but the 1225C will not boot from it. So how do I install Ubuntu?

Also, anyone thinking of buying this from Adorama Camera, be warned that they sell the 1225C WITHOUT an operating system and the BIOS has no option for installation from a USB stick. After going back to their website I do see that they do say "no OS" so it is my fault for not reading more carefully.

Comment: Does it have a cdrom/dvd player?

Comment: google: http://nongeekrecipes.org/2011/03/04/i-have-an-asus-eee-pc-and-i-cant-boot-from-a-bootable-usb-key-what-should-i-do/#comment-339

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the Asus 1225C

First I recommend updating the BIOS. Download the latest version from the Asus support site and install through the BIOS menu. This is probably not essential but does include an Ubuntu update!

I had problems installing from USB. I reset the BIOS setting to the default and it recognized and booted from the USB. The only difference in the BIOS that I have spotted is the CPUID maximum enabled.

Hope that gets you started. I'm still struggling with the accelerated graphics...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! To avoid confusion it'd be helpful to add the correct Asus support site relevant to updating to the *latest* BIOS to your answer.